# How would you create this glass material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I am working on a project where I need this glass material that has frosted glass on the outside. I have tried numerous node setups but they all seem to look off. I have tried glass bsdf with just about all roughnesses, glass bsdf mixed with translucency, glass shaders downloaded from the internet (like chocofurs node groups), but I can not seem to get the materials right.

Here is an imgur link to two versions that I have tried and rendered. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbHLa.jpg

Here is an imgur link to the actual object I'm trying to recreate. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K4GS.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Objects will appear flat if rendered in a plain environment. Try adding an HDR environment for the illumination or add some objects around the glass to be reflected and/or cast shadows to put it into some context rather than a uniform white environment. Also, objects in the real world have flaws and imperfections - try including some noise in your material to add some natural variation to the glossiness and roughness.

Comment: I actually am using an hdri. The white background is just something I added to make it like a product shot. And thank you for your help!